# Spring + Hibernate: Query Plan Cache Memory usage

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot

I'm programming an application with the latest version of Spring Boot. I recently became problems with  growing heap, that can not be garbage collected. The analysis of the heap with Eclipse MAT showed that, within one hour of running the application, the heap grew to 630MB and with Hibernate's SessionFactoryImpl using more than 75% of the whole heap.

[image]

Is was looking for possible sources around the Query Plan Cache, but the only thing I found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359088/high-memory-usage-when-using-hibernate), but that did not play out. The properties were set like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_soft_references=1024
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_strong_references=64
```

The database queries are all generated by the Spring's Query magic, using repository interfaces like [in this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation). There are about 20 different queries generated with this technique. No other native SQL or HQL are used.
Sample:

```
@Transactional
public interface TrendingTopicRepository extends JpaRepository<TrendingTopic, Integer> {
    List<TrendingTopic> findByNameAndSource(String name, String source);
    List<TrendingTopic> findByDateBetween(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd);
    Long countByDateBetweenAndName(Date dateStart, Date dateEnd, String name);
}
```

or

```
List<SomeObject> findByNameAndUrlIn(String name, Collection<String> urls);
```

as example for IN usage.

Question is: Why does the query plan cache keep growing (it does not stop, it ends in a full heap) and how to prevent this? Did anyone encounter a similar problem?

Versions:

- Spring Boot 1.2.5
- Hibernate 4.3.10

Comment: Post some code and configuration. Have you configured the properties as mentioned in the post you linked to? When adding them to the `application.properties` make sure you prefix them with `spring.pa.properties` else they won't be applied. Also please add the version of Hibernate you are using.

Comment: Updated the text with versions and examples

Comment: Are you configuring things yourself in your application class or another `@Configuration` class? If si please add.

Comment: No, only an connection pool (hikaricp) but i guess that is not relevant to this? Everything else comes from `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Comment: Try adding the new properties `hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size` and `hibernate.query.plan_parameter_metadata_max_size` the others have been deprecated for a while.

Comment: It seems to work for now, if I set those parameters very low (16 and 128)

Comment: @LastElb I am facing same issue with QueryPlanCache. Heap never stops growing. Setting hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size and hibernate.query.plan_parameter_metadata_max_size is the only way or you configured few other params as well

Comment: @Harshawardhan No, those two were the only ones. It still works to date with these parameters adjusted to low values (as listed above)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I've hit this issue as well. It basically boils down to having variable number of values in your IN clause and Hibernate trying to cache those query plans.

There are two great blog posts on this topic.
[The first](http://technodibble.blogspot.com.ee/2015/02/hibernate-in-clause-outofmemory.html):

> Using Hibernate 4.2 and MySQL in a project with an in-clause query
>   such as: `select t from Thing t where t.id in (?)`
>
> Hibernate caches these parsed HQL queries. Specifically the Hibernate
>   `SessionFactoryImpl` has `QueryPlanCache` with `queryPlanCache` and
>   `parameterMetadataCache`. But this proved to be a problem when the
>   number of parameters for the in-clause is large and varies.
>
> These caches grow for every distinct query. So this query with 6000
>   parameters is not the same as 6001.
>
> The in-clause query is expanded to the number of parameters in the
>   collection. Metadata is included in the query plan for each parameter
>   in the query,  including a generated name like x10_, x11_ , etc.
>
> Imagine 4000 different variations in the number of in-clause parameter
>   counts, each of these with an average of 4000 parameters. The query
>   metadata for each parameter quickly adds up in memory, filling up the
>   heap, since it can't be garbage collected.
>
> This continues until all different variations in the query parameter
>   count is cached or the JVM runs out of heap memory and starts throwing
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.
>
> Avoiding in-clauses is an option, as well as using a fixed collection
>   size for the parameter (or at least a smaller size).
>
> For configuring the query plan cache max size, see the property
>   `hibernate.query.plan_cache_max_size`, defaulting to `2048` (easily too
>   large for queries with many parameters).

And [second](http://dimovelev.blogspot.com.ee/2015/02/performance-pitfalls-hibernate-query.html) (also referenced from the first):

> Hibernate internally uses a [cache](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.3.Final/org/hibernate/engine/query/spi/QueryPlanCache.java) that maps HQL statements (as
>   strings) to [query plans](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.3.Final/org/hibernate/engine/query/spi/HQLQueryPlan.java). The cache consists of a bounded map limited
>   by default to 2048 elements (configurable). All HQL queries are loaded
>   through this cache. In case of a miss, the entry is automatically
>   added to the cache. This makes it very susceptible to thrashing - a
>   scenario in which we constantly put new entries into the cache without
>   ever reusing them and thus preventing the cache from bringing any
>   performance gains (it even adds some cache management overhead). To
>   make things worse, it is hard to detect this situation by chance - you
>   have to explicitly profile the cache in order to notice that you have
>   a problem there. I will say a few words on how this could be done
>   later on.
>
> So the cache thrashing results from new queries being generated at
>   high rates. This can be caused by a multitude of issues. The two most
>   common that I have seen are - bugs in hibernate which cause parameters
>   to be rendered in the JPQL statement instead of being passed as
>   parameters and the use of an "in" - clause.
>
> Due to some obscure bugs in hibernate, there are situations when
>   parameters are not handled correctly and are rendered into the JPQL
>   query (as an example check out [HHH-6280](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6280)). If you have a query that is
>   affected by such defects and it is executed at high rates, it will
>   thrash your query plan cache because each JPQL query generated is
>   almost unique (containing IDs of your entities for example).
>
> The second issue lays in the way that hibernate processes queries with
>   an "in" clause (e.g. give me all person entities whose company id
>   field is one of 1, 2, 10, 18). For each distinct number of parameters
>   in the "in"-clause, hibernate will produce a different query - e.g.
>   `select x from Person x where x.company.id in (:id0_)` for 1 parameter,
>   `select x from Person x where x.company.id in (:id0_, :id1_)` for 2
>   parameters and so on. All these queries are considered different, as
>   far as the query plan cache is concerned, resulting again in cache
>   thrashing. You could probably work around this issue by writing a
>   utility class to produce only certain number of parameters - e.g. 1,
>   10, 100, 200, 500, 1000. If you, for example, pass 22 parameters, it
>   will return a list of 100 elements with the 22 parameters included in
>   it and the remaining 78 parameters set to an impossible value (e.g. -1
>   for IDs used for foreign keys). I agree that this is an ugly hack but
>   could get the job done. As a result you will only have at most 6
>   unique queries in your cache and thus reduce thrashing.
>
> So how do you find out that you have the issue? You could write some
>   additional code and expose metrics with the number of entries in the
>   cache e.g. over JMX, tune logging and analyze the logs, etc. If you do
>   not want to (or can not) modify the application, you could just dump
>   the heap and run this OQL query against it (e.g. using [mat](https://eclipse.org/mat/)): `SELECT l.query.toString() FROM INSTANCEOF org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache$HQLQueryPlanKey l`. It
>   will output all queries currently located in any query plan cache on
>   your heap. It should be pretty easy to spot whether you are affected
>   by any of the aforementioned problems.
>
> As far as the performance impact goes, it is hard to say as it depends
>   on too many factors. I have seen a very trivial query causing 10-20 ms
>   of overhead spent in creating a new HQL query plan. In general, if
>   there is a cache somewhere, there must be a good reason for that - a
>   miss is probably expensive so your should try to avoid misses as much
>   as possible. Last but not least, your database will have to handle
>   large amounts of unique SQL statements too - causing it to parse them
>   and maybe create different execution plans for every one of them.

Comment: Thanks, a lot! We have faced the same issue and done tons of work to optimize our code. However, reason was found only after we have enable heapDumpOnOutOfMemoryErrors option for java while starting tomcat. heap dump have shown exact the same issue as you have described above.

Comment: Came across exactly the same issue. Spent a week finding out for the cause. Finally the heapdump gave the picture. After that, searched for "JPA query cache" and ended up here.

Comment: hi. I found your answer and I saw this problem in our application deployed at Wildfly 10.1. Same application in Wildfly 16.0.0 (using hibernate 5.3.9) and with the recommended property set generated "clear" query cache. the weird thing is that since default value is 2048, how can this oql produce in our cae 3,8K cached queries? how is this possible?

Comment: Don't know, I'm not an Hibernate expert. Ask your own question on StackOverflow or ask from Hibernate users/developers.

Comment: Please see Alex's answer below for an easier way to provide for this using `hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding=true` as long as you are on Hibernate 5.2.17 or higher.

Answer (score 18):

I have same problems with many(>10000) parameters in IN-queries. The number of my parameters is always different and I can not predict this, my `QueryCachePlan` growing too fast.

For database systems supporting execution plan caching, there's a better chance of hitting the cache if the number of possible IN clause parameters lowers.

Fortunately Hibernate of version 5.2.18 and higher has a solution with padding of parameters in IN-clause.

Hibernate can expand the bind parameters to power-of-two: 4, 8, 16, 32, 64.
This way, an IN clause with 5, 6, or 7 bind parameters will use the 8 IN clause, therefore reusing its execution plan.

If you want to activate this feature, you need to set this property to true `hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding=true`.

For more information see [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/improve-statement-caching-efficiency-in-clause-parameter-padding/), [atlassian](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12469).

Comment: The article says Hibernate 5.2.18 rather than 5.3.0.  The Atlassian link says both.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem using Spring Boot 1.5.7 with Spring Data (Hibernate) and the following config solved the problem (memory leak):

```
spring:
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        query:
          plan_cache_max_size: 64
          plan_parameter_metadata_max_size: 32
```

Comment: Here you may have performance loss. If you fix plan cache size, but still don't fix the actual query that fills the cache - all your cache may get filled with that bad query, leaving no room to cache other queries. So the cache may be busy with that bad query most of the time, and **performance of other queries may degrade**  since they are not getting cached properly or get evicted from cache too soon.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Hibernate 5.2.12, you can specify a hibernate configuration property to change how literals are to be bound to the underlying JDBC prepared statements by using the following:

```
hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode=BIND
```

From the Java documentation, this configuration property has 3 settings

1. AUTO (default)
2. BIND - Increases the likelihood of jdbc statement caching using bind parameters.
3. INLINE - Inlines the values rather than using parameters (be careful of SQL injection).

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR: Try to replace the IN() queries with ANY() or eliminate them

**Explanation:**
If a query contains IN(...) then a plan is created for each amount of values inside IN(...), since the *query* is different each time.
So if you have IN('a','b','c') and IN ('a','b','c','d','e') - those are two different query strings/plans to cache. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40017486/9947215) tells more about it.
In case of ANY(...) a single (array) parameter can be passed, so the query string will remain the same and the prepared statement plan will be cached once (example given below).

**Cause:**
This line might cause the issue:

```
List<SomeObject> findByNameAndUrlIn(String name, Collection<String> urls);
```

as under the hood it generates different IN() queries for every amount of values in "urls" collection.

**Warning:**
**You may have IN() query without writing it and even without knowing about it.**
ORM's such as Hibernate may generate them in the background - sometimes in unexpected places and sometimes in a non-optimal ways.
So consider enabling query logs to see the actual queries you have.

**Fix:**
Here is a (pseudo)code that may fix issue:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM trending_topic t WHERE t.name=? AND t.url=?"
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryTemplate);
currentPreparedStatement.setString(1, name); // safely replace first query parameter with name
currentPreparedStatement.setArray(2, connection.createArrayOf("text", urls.toArray())); // replace 2nd parameter with array of texts, like "=ANY(ARRAY['aaa','bbb'])"
```

**But:**
Don't take any solution as a ready-to-use answer. Make sure to test the final performance on actual/big data before going to production - no matter which answer you choose.
Why? Because IN and ANY both have pros and cons, and they can bring serious performance issues if used improperly (see examples in references below). Also make sure to use [parameter binding](https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection) to avoid security issues as well.

**References:**
[100x faster Postgres performance by changing 1 line](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line/) - performance of Any(ARRAY[]) vs ANY(VALUES())
[Index not used with =any() but used with in](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125413/index-not-used-with-any-but-used-with-in) - different performance of IN and ANY
[Understanding SQL Server query plan cache](https://www.sqlshack.com/understanding-sql-server-query-plan-cache/)

Hope this helps. Make sure to leave a feedback whether it worked or not - in order to help people like you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, the issue is because you are creating the query and not using the PreparedStatement. So what happens here is for each query with different parameters it creates an execution plan and caches it. 
If you use a prepared statement then you should see a major improvement in the memory being used.

Comment: Can you give one example with code of query and preparedstatement

Answer (score 1):

I had a big issue with this queryPlanCache, so I did a Hibernate cache monitor to see the queries in the queryPlanCache.
I am using in QA environment as a Spring task each 5 minutes.
I found which IN queries I had to change to solve my cache problem.
A detail is: I am using Hibernate 4.2.18 and I don't know if will be useful with other versions.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory;
import org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.hibernate.internal.util.collections.BoundedConcurrentHashMap;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.dao.GenericDAO;

public class CacheMonitor {

private final Logger logger  = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "MyPU")
private void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
    HibernateEntityManagerFactory hemf = (HibernateEntityManagerFactory) entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory();
    sessionFactory = (SessionFactoryImpl) hemf.getSessionFactory();
    fillQueryMaps();
}

private SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory;
private BoundedConcurrentHashMap queryPlanCache;
private BoundedConcurrentHashMap parameterMetadataCache;

/*
 * I tried to use a MAP and use compare compareToIgnoreCase.
 * But remember this is causing memory leak. Doing this
 * you will explode the memory faster that it already was.
 */

public void log() {
    if (!logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        return;
    }

    if (queryPlanCache != null) {
        long cacheSize = queryPlanCache.size();
        logger.debug(String.format("QueryPlanCache size is :%s ", Long.toString(cacheSize)));

        for (Object key : queryPlanCache.keySet()) {
            int filterKeysSize = 0;
            // QueryPlanCache.HQLQueryPlanKey (Inner Class)
            Object queryValue = getValueByField(key, "query", false);
            if (queryValue == null) {
                // NativeSQLQuerySpecification
                queryValue = getValueByField(key, "queryString");
                filterKeysSize = ((Set) getValueByField(key, "querySpaces")).size();
                if (queryValue != null) {
                    writeLog(queryValue, filterKeysSize, false);
                }
            } else {
                filterKeysSize = ((Set) getValueByField(key, "filterKeys")).size();
                writeLog(queryValue, filterKeysSize, true);
            }
        }
    }

    if (parameterMetadataCache != null) {
        long cacheSize = parameterMetadataCache.size();
        logger.debug(String.format("ParameterMetadataCache size is :%s ", Long.toString(cacheSize)));
        for (Object key : parameterMetadataCache.keySet()) {
            logger.debug("Query:{}", key);
        }
    }
}

private void writeLog(Object query, Integer size, boolean b) {
    if (query == null || query.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(b == true ? "JPQL " : "NATIVE ");
    builder.append("filterKeysSize").append(":").append(size);
    builder.append("\n").append(query).append("\n");
    logger.debug(builder.toString());
}

private void fillQueryMaps() {
    Field queryPlanCacheSessionField = null;
    Field queryPlanCacheField = null;
    Field parameterMetadataCacheField = null;
    try {
        queryPlanCacheSessionField = searchField(sessionFactory.getClass(), "queryPlanCache");
        queryPlanCacheSessionField.setAccessible(true);
        queryPlanCacheField = searchField(queryPlanCacheSessionField.get(sessionFactory).getClass(), "queryPlanCache");
        queryPlanCacheField.setAccessible(true);
        parameterMetadataCacheField = searchField(queryPlanCacheSessionField.get(sessionFactory).getClass(), "parameterMetadataCache");
        parameterMetadataCacheField.setAccessible(true);
        queryPlanCache = (BoundedConcurrentHashMap) queryPlanCacheField.get(queryPlanCacheSessionField.get(sessionFactory));
        parameterMetadataCache = (BoundedConcurrentHashMap) parameterMetadataCacheField.get(queryPlanCacheSessionField.get(sessionFactory));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed fillQueryMaps", e);
    } finally {
        queryPlanCacheSessionField.setAccessible(false);
        queryPlanCacheField.setAccessible(false);
        parameterMetadataCacheField.setAccessible(false);
    }
}

private <T> T getValueByField(Object toBeSearched, String fieldName) {
    return getValueByField(toBeSearched, fieldName, true);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private <T> T getValueByField(Object toBeSearched, String fieldName, boolean logErro) {
    Boolean accessible = null;
    Field f = null;
    try {
        f = searchField(toBeSearched.getClass(), fieldName, logErro);
        accessible = f.isAccessible();
        f.setAccessible(true);
    return (T) f.get(toBeSearched);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (logErro) {
            logger.error("Field: {} error trying to get for: {}", fieldName, toBeSearched.getClass().getName());
        }
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (accessible != null) {
            f.setAccessible(accessible);
        }
    }
}

private Field searchField(Class<?> type, String fieldName) {
    return searchField(type, fieldName, true);
}

private Field searchField(Class<?> type, String fieldName, boolean log) {

    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<Field>();
    for (Class<?> c = type; c != null; c = c.getSuperclass()) {
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(c.getDeclaredFields()));
        for (Field f : c.getDeclaredFields()) {

            if (fieldName.equals(f.getName())) {
                return f;
            }
        }
    }
    if (log) {
        logger.warn("Field: {} not found for type: {}", fieldName, type.getName());
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We also had a QueryPlanCache with growing heap usage. We had IN-queries which we rewrote, and additionally we have queries which use custom types. Turned out that the Hibernate class CustomType didn't properly implement equals and hashCode thereby creating a new key for every query instance. This is now solved in Hibernate 5.3. 
See https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12463. 
You still need to properly implement equals/hashCode in your userTypes to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1):

We had faced this issue with query plan cache growing too fast and old gen heap was also growing along with it as gc was unable to collect it.The culprit was JPA query taking some more than 200000 ids in the IN clause. To optimise the query we used joins instead of fetching ids from one table and passing those in other table select query..

Answer (score 1):

Alex's answer was helpful in understanding that the clause parameter padding property was available in hibernate.

But the mentioned property `hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding=true` didn't work as expected.

We can validate it by enabling hibernate logs

`spring.jpa.show-sql=true`

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true`

The above two properties will print the hibernate generated query in logs.

Found the below mentioned property working.

1. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.in_clause_parameter_padding=true`