# Why my web application hibernate retained so much memory?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, memory-leaks

My web application is build base on hibernate 4.2.5 + spring 3.2.4;

We use YourKit to take a snapshot while the application does not response to any request (or something just response and error page).

We found that:
       the memory of tomcat : 4G (option : Xmx2G)

The images are YourKit's snapshot Memory information.

Sorry for my cheap reputation, I can't post the images.

Thanks for help.

[Memory - class - sort by Shallow size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZngk.jpg): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZngk.jpg]

[Memory - class - sort by Retained size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSri.jpg): [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSSri.jpg]

Comment: It could be normal depending on how you are using hibernate (maybe incorrectly). How long does your application run before it reaches liveness failure? This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359088/high-memory-usage-when-using-hibernate

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And the application run about 4 days before it reaches failure. En. After read the topic, I do think that I need to read about the hibernate's query plan related document and source. Thank you very much.